# MySQL Full Text Search with short word as keyword returns no results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want to search for text `'law'` in MySQL colum 'content(colume_name)' that has value `'this is law'`.
I am using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `stuff` WHERE match(content) against('law' in boolean mode)
```

But the query above returns 0 rows. Can someone explain why there are no results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you check the system variable: `ft_min_word_len`?
ususally it's set to 4, so words with length < 4 are not included in the `FULLTEXT` index.

see: [11.8.6 Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)